# Will a good dream from Allah always come true?

Tags: dream

I know about the 3 types of dreams. However, I am wondering if a good dream from Allah will always materialize and come true ? Or are there instances where it does not ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about a dream coming true exactly as was visioned. Rather it is about the interpretation.
There are numerous instances of such dreams mentioned in the Qur'an, especially in chapter 10, Surah Yusuf.

Comment: Thanks for your response but you have not answered the question. Let's assume the interpretation is right. Do they always come true ? This is a Yes or No question.

Comment: Not the way we usually think. Good dreams are from Allah subhanahuwataala. The purpose of a dream may be multifold. I dream maybe a harbinger of something to come. But it may also be a warning or advice or a command. Yes, they do come true, but not exact;y in the literal sense, some things may be symbolic. There is a detailed response here https://islamqa.info/en/answers/67624/different-types-of-dreams-is-there-any-kind-of-warning-dream if you haven't seen it already.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying ! I was referring to a good dream that foretells something good to come in the future. I thought if it is from Allah, it always comes true but someone said that not always, because if the person sins for example, Allah might keep the good dream away from coming true.  That same person also said that Allah might not let the good dream come true but instead the good from the dream is instead used as a way to prevent or block a calamity or a trial. That did not make sense to me. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that doesn't make sense. There is no such thing as Allah withholding a good dream from coming true.

Because a good dream ( not a warning or command where you have to do something but a dream where Allah will do something for you) is a promise from Allah and a promise from Allah comes true .

When Prophet Yusf saw 11 stars bowing down to him, it was a promise from Allah. However, when Prophet Ibrahim saw the sacrifice of his son, it was a command from Allah.

Please tell us a little bit about your dream. Thank you